# Flutter Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow on cloud_firestore after hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

Currently working on a Flutter Firestore after updating to latest version it start causing the problem The application works good but when i click **hot reload** it start displaying this error.

I thought there might be a problem in cache. So I did flutter clean but the result is same.

Here the version i am using cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1

````
E/flutter (22725): #0      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #1      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #2      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #3      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #4      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #5      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #6      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #7      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #8      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #9      main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #10     main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #11     main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #12     main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13     main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #14     main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): ...
E/flutter (22725): ...
E/flutter (22725): #13207  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13208  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13209  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13210  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13211  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13212  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13213  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13214  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13215  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13216  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13217  main (file:///...../FlutterProject/bntbladi/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart:51:40)
E/flutter (22725): #13218  _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:140:38)
E/flutter (22725): #13219  _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter (22725): #13220  _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (22725): #13221  _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
E/flutter (22725): #13222  runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
E/flutter (22725): #13223  _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:138:5)
E/flutter (22725): #13224  _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
E/flutter (22725): #13225  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)```
````

Comment: Whenever you make changes on your project(ex. adding package,editing android/ios files. You have to close your current debug session, run on terminal `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, then rerun your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling `cloud_firestore` from your `pubspec.yaml` file,
running `flutter pub get`, and finally reinstalling `cloud_firestore` back. It should work.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Yes there was some implementation of the plugin was not i have added when i added the error fixed.